# Failed to start jekyll service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, centos7, systemd, website-deployment

I am following a guide to install jekyll on my server(running CentOS 7) , as I want to get better at web development as a hobby. Disclaimer, I am not using a reverse proxy on this server as I want to learn the general setup of the website and get to know jekyll before creating something more permenant.
This is the guide I have used, as I haven't found anything better yet:
https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jekyll-on-centos-7/ 
Some of the commands needed to be adjusted for newer versions of things like RVM, as this guide is a little bit old.

So the issue that I've run into is when I am instructed to make the systemd service file for jekyll. The code recommended to me in the guide is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jekyll service
After=syslog.target
After=network.target[Service]
User=jekyll
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/jekyll serve --source 
"/home/jekyll/"
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=jekyll 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It simply will not start. When I enabled, it created the link just fine, however, refuses to start.(I tried changing the 2.3.3 to 2.4.1, since its the version of ruby I'm using, however is still fails to start.) I have no experience writing `systemd` files, so I am stuck here until I can learn what I need to change and why.

When checking the status, these are the log messages that I get:

```
May 13 12:37:46 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:23] Invalid section header '[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:7] Failed to add dependency on network.target[Service], ignoring: Invalid argument
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:9] Unknown lvalue 'User' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:11] Unknown lvalue 'Type' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:13] Unknown lvalue 'ExecStart' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:15] Unknown lvalue 'Restart' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:17] Unknown lvalue 'StandardOutput' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'StandardError' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:21] Unknown lvalue 'SyslogIdentifier' in section 'Unit'
May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:23] Invalid section header '[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target'
```

Any help is appreciated, and I would love to be given an explanation of "why?" for any tips or fixes offered, as I am looking to learn as much as I can.

Thank you!

Edit 1: Added systemctl status messages

Answer (score 0):

## Your unit file is syntactically incorrect.

> ```
> May 13 12:37:46 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:23] Invalid section header '[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target'
> ```

You forgot a linebreak between the `[Install]` section header and the `WantedBy=` directive.

> ```
> May 13 12:37:50 li1018-116.members.linode.com systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/jekyll.service:7] Failed to add dependency on network.target[Service], ignoring: Invalid argument
> ```

You forgot a linebreak between the `After=` directive and the `[Service]` section header.

All remaining reported errors are consequences of these two.